# Why does h:selectOneRadio does not have a "name" attribute?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, custom-component

I want to do some crazy grouping with SelectOneRadio, so I decide to create my own custom component that allow me to specify the `name` attribute of the `<input>` tag (as you know, same `name` means the radio buttons are in the same group). The renderer is correct, so I have a `<input>` that used to render like this

```
<input name="myForm:test1" id="myForm:test1:0" value="0" type="radio">
```

now render like this

```
<input name="foo" id="myForm:test1:0" value="0" type="radio">
```

However, EL stop working when I submit a form (same for h:commandButton and p:commandButton). So if I have this

```
<xxx:selectOneRadio id="test1" value="#{myBean.selectedFood}">
```

then EL work, `selectedFood` print out the corrected value, but if I put in

```
<xxx:selectOneRadio id="test1" value="#{myBean.selectedFood}" groupId="foo">
```

which will make the `name=foo` in the `<input>` tag. Then EL binding stop working. `selectedFood` is `null`.

More interestingly, If I put in this

```
<xxx:selectOneRadio id="test1" value="#{myBean.selectedFood}" groupId="myForm:test1">
```

which `myForm:test1` is the correct client Id, then EL binding work again, so it does not look like it is my code that make the binding stop working. **Does JSF require the `name` attribute of the `input` tag to the client id?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` becomes the HTTP request parameter name and this has to be used to collect submitted HTTP request parameter values. This defaults to the JSF component client ID and the collecting happens in the `decode()` method of the `Renderer` (or the `UIComponent` itself). You need to override/implement the `decode()` of the `Renderer` as well to change the way how you get request parameter values.

Comment: The more I think about it, this does not seems like a good design sighhh back to square 1